# getting an object's name when passed as an argument (tried using template literal)

Tags: javascript, object, template-literals

trying to get an object's name to create a template literal that references said object. Gets [object Object] instead of theObject.

```
const theObject = {
    prop1: "sth",
    prop2: "sthesee"
}
function theFun(theArg) {
    console.log(`${theArg}`);//logs [object Object]
}
theFun(theObject);
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, **tell other readers what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: _"//logs [object Object]"_ - As it should because `\`${theArg}\`` is the same as `theArg.toString()` which results in `[object Object]`

Comment: Objects don't have names in the general case. There is no name associated with the object you've shown. The binding (variable/constant) that refers to it has a name, but the object does not, and it's the *value* of the binding (the reference to the object) that gets passed, not the binding. You could add a property to the object that gives some kind of name to it, but that won't help you use the constant. But this sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/): What makes you think you want that name?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder great thanks. yes most likely it's a misguided question but now I know objects don't have names so it served as a lesson.